# Parsing multiple "To:" from raw email in Python

Tags: python, email

Im using the `email` module with Python3.7 to parse a raw email.

The value for the `To:` field is the string

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_file(fh)
print(msg.get('To')) 
#---> "name a" <aaa@email.com>,\n "name b"\n\t<bbbb@email.com>
```

What would be the easiest and fail-proof way to obtain a list of `To:` addresses like:

`["aaa@email.com", "bbbb@email.com"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`email.utils.getaddresses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.getaddresses) on `msg.get('To')`... eg:

```
to_list = msg.get('To')
emails = email.utils.getaddresses([to_list])
```

Will give you (given your example) 2-tuples of:

```
[('name a', 'aaa@email.com'), ('name b', 'bbbb@email.com')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Emails in Python are stored in a data structure similar to a multidict with case-insensitive keys. Recipient addresses are stored in the named header field "to".

So, the easiest way is to use [`EmailMessage.get_all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_all):

```
>>> msg.get_all("to")
["aaa@email.com", "bbbb@email.com"]
```

*This basic usage assumes the email message was parsed correctly in the first place*. The output shown in OP's question suggests that they have a problem earlier on (corrupt input data format), because the email from file was not parsed correctly.